# Content type/UTI to open CSV in app

Tags: cocoa-touch, csv, plist, uti

How can I write the CFBundleDocumentTypes property of my .plist file, to allow the app to be displayed in the "Open in..." dialog in the other applications?

That's mine, but it doesn't work

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Readings</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>text.csv</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Found it: `public.comma-separated-values-text`

Comment: Apple's constant is `kUTTypeCommaSeparatedText`.

Comment: From iOS 15 and macos Monterey becomes `UTType.commaSeparatedText`

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the general UTI provided by Apple ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH202-CHDHIJDE) fig 1-2). In your case public.text should be enough, but you might be interested into public.composite-content if you want handle for instance .doc and .docx files as well.

Your code might be modified as follow

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Readings</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
           <string>public.text</string>
           <string>public.html</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```